# Finding difference in 2 shapefiles and deleting the difference

Tags: qgis

I have 2 shapefiles: shapefile A (yellow) and shapefile B (purple). I already did some basic data cleanup on shapefile A, but now want to use shapefile B because it has less overlaps between polygons.

How can I detect the difference between the 2 shapefiles? Basically I want to remove the differences. So in the following image, the purple polygons on the right (shapefile B) should not be there as they were already removed in shapefile A.

[image]

I tried in the Difference tool in QGIS but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work to [Select by location](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_selection_tools/selectbylocation.html) for features that touch and then inverse the selection?

Comment: Just tried it with a bunch of different options and doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Create  signature, e.g.concatenate centroid coordinates, perimeter. Join to find matches. Switch selection

Answer (score 1):

You could to use "Spatial Query" plugin:

- Layer A
- Where the feature = Equals
- Layer B

And then you'll need to invert the selection to obtain the polygons that are not equal.

Comment: Tried this but it results in 0 selected features.